# If $A$ is a $2\times 2$ non-diagonal diagonalizable matrix then have two distinct eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Let $A$ be a $2\times 2$ non-diagonal real matrix. I know that if it has two distinct real eigenvalues then it is diagonalizable. I would like to know if the reverse is also true, that is, matrix $A$ is digitizable if it has two distinct (real) eigenvalues.

Obviously if I remove the hypothesis to be non-diagonal, then it is not true, as can be seen in these other questions. [Q1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3746618/is-it-true-that-a-2x2-matrix-is-diagonalizable-iff-it-has-two-distinct-eigenvalu) and [Q2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2282091/diagonalisability-of-2%C3%972-matrices-with-repeated-eigenvalues)

I tried to create an example of a non-diagonal matrix with equal eigenvalues that is diagonalizable, but I couldn't. But, in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3746618/is-it-true-that-a-2x2-matrix-is-diagonalizable-iff-it-has-two-distinct-eigenvalu?rq=1#comment7704649_3746618) comment, it is said that my statement is true,but I couldn't prove it.

I thought this theorem could help me, but I was unable to apply it in the direction I want.

> Let $T:V\to V$  be a linear operator, in a space of finite dimension and let $\lambda_1,\cdots \lambda_t$ be its distinct eigenvalues. The following statements are equivalent:
>
> 1. A is diagonalizable
> 2. $p_T(x)=(x-\lambda_1)^{n_1}\cdots (x-\lambda_t)^{n_t},n_i\ge 1$ and $\gamma_{T}(\lambda_i)=\mu_{T}(\lambda_i)$
> 3. $\dim V=\sum_{i=1}^{t}\dim Aut_A(\lambda_i)$
>
> where $\gamma_{T}(\lambda_i)$ and $\mu_{T}(\lambda_i)$ are [geometric
> multiplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Eigenspaces,_geometric_multiplicity,_and_the_eigenbasis_for_matrices) and [algebraic multiplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Algebraic_multiplicity), respectively.

Is it possible to prove that if $A$, (not diagonal) is diagonalizable, then it has two distinct real eigenvalues with the theorem above? Or does anyone have any suggestions for another useful result.

Comment: Any $2\times 2$ diagonalizable matrix with repeated eigenvalues is a multiple of the identity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is non-diagonal and diagonalizable. By contradiction, suppose also that it has only one eigenvalue $\lambda$ repeated two times.

Since $A$ is diagonalizable, you have a base-change matrix $M$ such that $A=MDM^{-1}$ with $D$ a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalue. Since $A$ has only one eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity 2, then $D=\lambda I$. As a consequence,
$$A = M \lambda IM^{-1} = \lambda MM^{-1} = \lambda I$$
so $A$ is diagonal. Contradiction.

Comment: I'd reformulate the proof without contradiction. If $A$ is a diagonalizable $2\times2$ matrix with an eigenvalue of multiplicity $2$, then it is diagonal.